# Getting values from addOnPreDrawListener()

Tags: android, android-viewtreeobserver

I have not understood how to return values from the method below, I have tried to return `int` but it shows me a weird error which is not possible to solve. This is the code:

```
private void showTheEnemy() {

    ViewTreeObserver vto = radarImage.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            radarImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            yradar_height = radarImage.getMeasuredHeight();
            xradar_width = radarImage.getMeasuredWidth();
            return true;
        }
    });
    coordinateText.setText(yradar_height + " " + xradar_width);
}
```

I have understood that values are not being updated in the method because when I use `setText()` method then `int` values are 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get zeros because the inner-method is not triggered before you set the text. The values are set at whatever they were when you last initialized them.

Set the text from the callback.

```
private TextView coordinateText;
private int xradar_width = 0;
private int yradar_height = 0;

private void showTheEnemy() {

    ViewTreeObserver vto = radarImage.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {

            yradar_height = radarImage.getMeasuredHeight();
            xradar_width = radarImage.getMeasuredWidth();

            coordinateText.setText(String.format("%d %d", 
                yradar_height,
                xradar_width 
            ));

            radarImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Your values are still 0 here

}
```

---

Or pass to another method.

```
private TextView coordinateText;

private void showTheEnemy() {

    ViewTreeObserver vto = radarImage.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {

         setCoordinate(coordinateText,  
                radarImage.getMeasuredHeight(),
                radarImage.getMeasuredWidth() ));
            radarImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return true;
        }
    });

}

private static void setCoordinate(TextView tv, int xPos, int yPos) {
     tv.setText(String.format("%d %d", xPos, yPos));
}
```

Comment: yes I did that, I understood that values are updated within the method, but what I need is that the integer values can be accessed from other methods.

Comment: You can access them from other methods. Just not until after the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Set values when you get radarImage width and height:

```
private void showTheEnemy() {
    ViewTreeObserver vto = radarImage.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            radarImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            yradar_height = radarImage.getMeasuredHeight();
            xradar_width = radarImage.getMeasuredWidth();
            coordinateText.setText(yradar_height + " " + xradar_width);
            return true;
        }
    });
    coordinateText.setText(yradar_height + " " + xradar_width);
}
```

EDIT:
Create class fields and when new values are provided pass those values where you need them.